# How to annotate anonymous object with optional property in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I have a JavaScript class that takes one argument of type Object with defined set of properties and the Closure Compiler is happy when I annotate it like:

```
@constructor
@param {{ subview:BaseView, el:(jQuery|Element), title:String }} options
var MyView = function(options){ }
```

I would like to make `title` key optional and pass `title` value to some instances of my class and implement fallback behavior when this key is not present, so I annotated my class with:

```
@constructor
@param {{ subview:BaseView, el:(jQuery|Element), title:String= }} options
var MyView = function(options){ }
```

and now Closure Compiler is complaining:

> WARNING - Bad type annotation. expected closing }

I've checked [Annotating JavaScript for the Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler), but I see no single line describing such use case.

Comment: I think the `=` modifier is only valid for function parameters, not for record type properties.

Answer (score 25):

`@param {{ subview:BaseView, el:(jQuery|Element), title:(string|undefined) }} options`

Comment: Instead of `|undefined` shouldn't it be `title?:string`?

Comment: Not for Closure Compiler, no.