# Preventing the defaults of unset object properties from being overridden in a JS function

Tags: javascript

So, I have a function with an object as a parameter:

```
function example(options = { param1: true, param2: 42 })
{
   return options.param2;
}
```

The problem is, if I call the function with parameters like this:

```
example({ param1: false });
```

the default for `options.param2` gets overridden and set to `undefined`, even though it wasn't defined when the function was called. I realize why this is (the object is all one parameter so the entire thing gets set when you call the function), but is there any easy way to prevent this from happening, short of making all of the object parameters their own arguments in the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructure the argument instead, and assign default destructured values.

```
function example({ param1 = true, param2 = 42 } = {}) {
   return param2;
}
```

Comment: perfect, also how would I JSDoc this? just use @param for each one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25778441 looks to do what you want